# C++: set::insert with iterators and sets of sets

Tags: c++, containers

I have a set of sets of ints called nets which I'm trying to iterate through to determine if either of the ints to or from have been added to an existing set; if so, I add them to the existing set (this is to keep track of all combinations of shorts on an electrical network).

However, I CANNOT get the set::insert function to work! I'm able to use (*it).count just fine to determine if either int has already been added to a set, but (*it).insert doesn't work (I always receive the error No matching member function call to 'insert'). However, if I just create a set of ints, setName.insert(to) works fine.

What's wrong with my code?

```
for (std::set<std::set<int>>::iterator it=nets.begin(); it!=nets.end(); ++it) {  
    if ((*it).count(to) || (*it).count(from)) {
        currentSet = (*it);
        (*it).insert(to);
        (*it).insert(from);
        addedToExistingSet = true;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `std::set` is an **associative container** that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type `T`, you cannot modify an object inside it because you would invalidate the `set`.

If it was allowed, you'd be allowed to change the items value out from under the container, potentially altering the ordering.

The standard says :

> **23.2.4 Associative containers [associative.reqmts]**
>
> `iterator` of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category. **For *associative containers* where the value type is the same as the key type, both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are constant iterators**.

You should consider using another container for the outer one like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to modify an object inside a set, which isn't a valid operation as you would invalidate the set.  Is there a reason you need the outer container to be a set?  Could it be a `std::vector` for example?